# dkms does not remove package

Tags: package-management, 15.04, alsa, dkms

It appears I am stuck in a loop with `dkms` where I cannot remove a package. See the following commands and output:

```
$ sudo dkms status | grep alsa

alsa-firewire, 3.11: added

$ sudo dkms remove alsa-firewire/3.11 --all

$ sudo dkms status | grep alsa

alsa-firewire, 3.11: added

$ sudo dkms install alsa-firewire/3.11

Error! This module/version has already been built on: 3.19.0-25-lowlatency
Directory: /var/lib/dkms/alsa-firewire/3.11/3.19.0-25-lowlatency/x86_64
already exists.  Use the dkms remove function before trying to build again
```

What's going on? How can I remove the `alsa-firewire` package so that I can reinstall it with a different version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In some cases `dkms remove` command does not remove the modules correctly.

This may happen, if you used `mkdsc` or other options of `dkms`.

It is quite safe to remove the module manually, if it is not installed according to `dkms status`.

You can do it by

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/dkms/alsa-firewire
```

---

Another notice. You incorrectly use `dkms install` command.

The correct way is

```
sudo dkms install -m alsa-firewire -v 3.11
```

Comment: an upvote and an edit!  :-)